# To fetch value of particular textbox

Tags: php, ajax, session, textbox

Here, I am using session to store multiple textbox value.
But when I am going to fetch from session, I am getting the same value for all textbox which is in session.

My code:

```
if ($order_list) {
     $i = $start +1; 
     foreach ($order_list as $row) 
     {
?>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="txt" autocomplete="off" id="txtid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['txtval'])) { echo $_SESSION['txtval'];} ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

In javascript:

```
$(document).on('blur','.txt',function(){
    var myVar = $(this).val();

    //alert(myVar);
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "view_orders_checked_array.php",
            data: {account: myVar, task: 'alltxt'},
            async: false
        });
 });
```

In view_orders_checked_array.php :

```
$task = $_GET['task'];
    if($task == "alltxt")
    {

        $_SESSION['txtval'] = $account;
    }
```

Here, I am not getting the value of particular textbox. I am getting the value which I have last inserted.
Where I am going wrong?

Comment: is it solved or u getting problem in this?

Comment: Thanks for asking but I am getting problem...@Zeeshan

Comment: check my below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below working code, if you just pass the id with your **txtval** and create session for each *id* **key** and **value** . Now when you print session array you will get all key values in session array. Please ask if difficult to understand.

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['txtval'] = '';
$order_list[0] = array('id'=>'1');
$order_list[1] = array('id'=>'2');
$order_list[2] = array('id'=>'3');
$order_list[3] = array('id'=>'4');

$start = '';
if ($order_list) {
    $i = $start + 1;
    foreach ($order_list as $row) {
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="txt" autocomplete="off"
               id="txtid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['txtval'])) {
            echo $_SESSION['txtval'];
        } ?>">
    <?php }
}?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('blur','.txt',function(){
        var myVar = $(this).val();
        var myVarid = this.id;
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "view_orders_checked_array.php",
                data: {account: myVar, task: 'alltxt', id: myVarid },
                async: false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
     });
</script>
```

**PHP file view_orders_checked_array.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$task = $_GET['task'];
if ($task == "alltxt") {

    $_SESSION['txtval'][$_REQUEST['id']] = $_REQUEST['account'];
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION['txtval'] );echo '</pre>';
die('Call');
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to maintain array in session also so that you can do with the help of ids

```
 var id=your loop id;
 data: {account: myVar, task: 'alltxt',id:id },
```

and in your view_orders_checked_array page

```
$task = $_GET['task'];
$id=$_GET['id'];
if($task == "alltxt")
{

    $_SESSION['txtval'][$id] = $account;
}
```

and in your code

```
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="txt" autocomplete="off" id="txtid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['txtval'])) { echo $_SESSION['txtval'][$row['id']];} ?>">
```

i suggest you to use `POST`  method for passing values

Comment: The thing which you have answer is only give the first character of textbox value.
So, this is not possible.

Comment: first character of textbox value???? have you printed session values i.e. complete session array???

Comment: what are you getting ??? you have to pass id's to store each textarea value uniquely, that you can do in many ways....

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are putting the same value in all text fields

```
$_SESSION['txtval']
```

in your loop is always the same.

Edit

And also I think you getting same last inserted value because instead to store all text fields in array $_SESSION['txtval']['another_id_key'] you storing it in $_SESSION['txtval'] which is only one value

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: Store values into array so you can easier grab more values.